# multiprocessing.Pool: get notified when a task is started

Tags: python, python-2.7, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I use `multiprocessing.Pool` like so to execute a number of tasks.

```py
def execute(task):
    # run task, return result
def on_completion(task_result):
    # process task result

async_results = [pool.apply_async(execute,
                                  args=[task],
                                  callback=on_completion)
                 for task in self.tasks]

# wait for results
```

My completion handler is invoked by the pool in a nice, serialized way so I don't have to worry about thread safety in its implementation.

However, I would also like to be notified when a task is started. Is there an elegant way to accomplish the following?

```py
def on_start(arg): # Whatever arg(s) were passed to the execute function
    # Called when task starts to run

pool.apply_async(run_task,
                 args=[task],
                 start_callback=on_start,
                 completion_callback=on_completion)
```

Comment: According to the [Process Pools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), the `Pool` constructor takes an optional _`initializer`_ argument and "If _`initializer`_ is not `None` then each worker process will call `initializer(*initargs)` when it starts" — which sounds like it could do (or is) what you want.

Comment: It says "each worker process [...] when it starts". I am interested in task starts. There could be many more tasks (thousands) than workers (tens, usually number of cores), hence not all tasks can be started immediately.

Comment: OK, for that you could define a relatively simple function decorator that first made some sort of a start notification call and then returned the result of calling the wrapped function.